# I want to know can I take two opposite directions of current in mesh analysis or I am bounded to take the direction of current same in mesh analysis

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

[image]

I want to know that in mesh analysis can we take the direction of current in different ways means in two meshes can we take on current direction in clockwise but other will be in anticlockwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose either direction. As an exercise, do the sums, then flip one current direction, and do the sums again. Notice the second one has the sign inverted?

We need to distinguish what's convenient, with what must happen, and what you might have been advised.

What must happen is that when you've chosen a direction for any current in any loop, you must stick with that, and use it consistently. If you reverse it half way through the calculation, you won't get the right answer.

Having examined the circuit, it may be convenient to chose this current this way, and that current that way, if you can spot that it leads perhaps to a nice cancellation. That's OK, just keep the choice you've made running through the calculation.

I tend to always label my currents counter-clockwise. Then I don't have to choose, and I don't catch myself out forgetting which sign I was using.

If your teacher or your supervisor suggests a particular way to choose, then go with that, it will make it easier to compare class notes if you've all attempted the problem the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The signs of the mesh current is arbitrary in mesh analysis as long as you make sure to keep track of the negative signs in the math.